# Are questions about the reasons behind a decision on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to understand why Automattic developers decide to only allow a handful of tag in comment section, or making it more intuitive. Is that on-topic? This doesn't seem to be addressed in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

<sup>FYI: [Expanding the allowed HTML tags in comments?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17947/64282)

Here is the question on main site: [Why are HTML tags limited in comment section?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/349294/64282)</sup>

Comment: Automattic has nothing to do with this stack. This stack is community driven, it isn't an official WP support avenue. Additionally, WordPress isn't an Automattic product, Automattic doesn't release WordPress, they're just a company with the same CEO as the founder of the project, and have rights to use the trademark, they don't determine how the WP project is ran, and a lot of people work on WP that don't work at Automattic. There's a lot of overlap yes, conflicts of interest even, but WP isn't an Automattic product

Comment: Oh, so it's just that the founder of WP also founded Automattic, so that they can provide wp.com? I thought the relationship is like how SO the company moderates SE, or Reddit the company moderates Reddit

Comment: Indeed, although there is a certain amount of politics around the subject, companies like to hire people who contribute to WP as it demonstrates their skill and raises their profile, and then some of those people apply to Automattic. As a bigger company it tends to outweigh the others as a result. Also SO/SE are the same, they actually leave the moderation to us users :) employees only intervene when something seriously bad happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this isn't a decision made by Automattic, but by the WordPress developers. Partially the same people, but a different group nonetheless.

Second, you can usually read the justifications in the Trac tickets for the component. Just copying these over to our site wouldn't be that useful.

But generally, yes, you can ask such a question on our site. We had similar questions in the past, for example about the [SVG format](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191536/for-what-security-reasons-are-svgs-blocked-in-the-media-uploader). The "intuitive" part of your question would probably be too much "primarily opinion based", but the selection of allowed HTML elements is not.
My guess is that the answer is: "only the absolutely necessary" for security reasons.

Comment: Which part is "intuitive" that you are refereeing to?

Comment: @Ooker Your "making it more intuitive".

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know why I wrote that. I mean more buttons so that commenters can use